# Have the razor pages in Identity been updated from Asp.Net Core 3 to Asp.Net 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have an Asp.Net Core 3 project with scaffolded Identity razor pages. Can I just copy them over after migrating to Asp.Net 5, or do I have to re-scaffold them? I have made a lot of changes to the pages, and I would hate to have to do all that work again.

**Update**

Seems to be ok to just copy. No errors spotted so far.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can also rebuild them.

After migrating an application or solution to .NET 5, clean and rebuild the application or solution. If there is a package incompatibility between the new package reference and the cached package:

1.Clear NuGet package caches by executing the following dotnet nuget locals command in a command shell:

```
dotnet nuget locals --clear all
```

2.Clean and rebuild the app or solution.

More specific details can be found in the official Microsoft documents:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio